# Animation with jQuery hide one div and show other smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I'm looking for some similar animation like this site when you hower on their slide it smoothly change slides but I don't know what plugin they are using and how I also try it doing myself with jquery and it works partially but not smooth and it hidden one shows in background

My Codes :

PS : I added transition in it but it cuts little bit of image not calculating properly

```js
function slideAnimation(n,e)
{
 var height = $('.'+e).height();

 var move = height*n;
 $('#slide').css('transform','translateY(-'+move+'px)');
 $('#slide').css('transition','transform 1s');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
        <li onmouseenter="slideAnimation(1,'first')" id="first">First</li>
     <li onmouseenter="slideAnimation(2,'second')" id="second">Second</li>
     <li onmouseenter="slideAnimation(3,'third')" id="third">Third</li>
    </ul>
    <div style="overflow: auto">
     <div id="slide" style="display:block;height:13px;transform: translateY(-13px); transition: transform 1s">
          <ul>
           <li class="a first"><img src="1.png"></li>
           <li class="a second"><img src="2.png"></li>
           <li class="a third"><img src="3.png"></li>
          </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem could be solve by adding a css rule to your animation components that defines the property `transition`, look here for more info https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/transition. Also you I advise you to take a look to https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/, it is a pure css animation library.

Comment: Hi I added transition but it cuts little bit of image I updated codes